# Is there a best practice in producing a series of columns filled with values based on logical checks?

Tags: r

Consider the following data:

```
mydf<-data.frame(ID=c('a','b','c','d','e'),
             home=c(0,2,1,0,0),
             aroundtown=c(0,3,0,1,2),
             outinspace=c(5,0,0,2,1))
```

My goal is to produce columns `_any` and `_exclusive` for each of `home`, `aroundtown`, and `outinspace`.  The `_any` columns should be filled with the original values associated with the `ID` and the variable.  The `_exclusive` columns should read 0 if there are no other columns for a given ID with a value other than zero. (As shown below).

[image]

I am able to get this done with the following:

```
 md2<-mydf%>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-ID)%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(tot=sum(value))%>%
  mutate(Exclusive=ifelse(value==tot,"Exclusive",""))%>%
  mutate(freq=ifelse(Exclusive=="",1,2))%>%
  select(-Exclusive)%>%
  uncount(freq)%>%
  group_by(ID,name)%>%
  mutate(exclusive=ifelse(cumsum(value)>value,"exclusive","Any"))%>%
  select(-tot)%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name,exclusive),values_from = value)%>%
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

I can't help but wonder if there is a better, or preferred-by-some, means of achieving this.

The ideal solution would

- Avoid explicitly naming `home`,`aroundtown`, and `outinspace`
- Have the flexibility to allow any number of variables beyond `ID`
- Allow for multiple logical checks similar in nature (for instance `_mostly` comes to mind), resulting in columns for each check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred solution would be to use something not necessarily computationally optimized but more readable and adaptable as several of your requirements involve that aspect.

I decided to separate each of your logical categories (any, exclusive) into different functions. This way, you can add whatever criteria you want in the future by creating a new function (for instance `is_Mostly`).

```
is_Any <- function(dfrow){
  return(dfrow)
}

is_Exclusive <- function(dfrow){
  nonzeros <- which(dfrow > 0)
  if (length(nonzeros) == 1){
    dfrow[!nonzeros] <- 0
    return(dfrow)
  }
  return(rep(0, length(dfrow)))
}

is_Mostly <- function(dfrow){
  dfrow[!dfrow == max(dfrow)] <- 0
  return(dfrow)
}
```

The master function will be called using the numerical columns of your choice (without naming them) and with the selected conditions.

```
add_new_columns <- function(df, columns, conditions){
  for (condition in conditions){
    eval_func <- eval(parse(text = paste0("is_", condition)))
    new_cols <- paste0(columns, "_", condition)
    df[, new_cols] <- t(apply(df[, columns], 1, eval_func))
  }
  return(df)
}

my_columns <- colnames(mydf)[-1]
my_conditions <- c("Any", "Exclusive")
mydf2 <- add_new_columns(mydf, my_columns, my_conditions)
mydf2
#  ID home aroundtown outinspace home_Any aroundtown_Any outinspace_Any home_Exclusive aroundtown_Exclusive outinspace_Exclusive
#1  a    0          0          5        0              0              5              0                    0                    5
#2  b    2          3          0        2              3              0              0                    0                    0
#3  c    1          0          0        1              0              0              1                    0                    0
#4  d    0          1          2        0              1              2              0                    0                    0
#5  e    0          2          1        0              2              1              0                    0                    0
```